# Adobe Edge Without Javascript files?

Tags: css, adobe-edge

Is there a way for Adobe Edge to output with only CSS3 so javascript doesnt have to be used? If not, is there something else I can use that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simple animations with CSS3 only. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations) is a useful resource.

This is the basic syntax:

```
  h1 {  
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;  
    -webkit-animation-name: colorchange;  
  }  

  @-webkit-keyframes colorchange {  
    0% {  
      color: #fff
    }   
    100% {  
      color: #000
  }
```

Comment: Is this with Adobe Edge? I am just looking for which program to use at the moment.. but I do want to use something so I can learn

Comment: No. It is plain CSS. All you need is a text editor, even something as simple as Notepad or TextEdit.

Comment: i would like to use a program for what im trying to do.. is there anything I can do with Adobe Edge to stop it from using javascript

Comment: is there a reason you want to use a program if you don't want javascript to be used?

Answer (score 0):

There are other editors out there. Edge is really not the ideal editor for a lot of applications. For one thing, it is pretty heavily reliant on Javascript. Entirely I believe. Edge, for me, seems more geared to non-flash animation with a more powerful api to control animations from the page.

**Other editors to look at:**

- Sencha animator
- Hype
- Purple for Mac

Purple, in particular seems like a good one for css3. It has a good, simple interface that can import psd files. But it is mac only.